# Visual Studio 2015 is not activating

Tags: visual-studio-2015

When i try to sign in using my microsoft account in visual studio it is not activating it

[below is the screenshot of problem i am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cs2u.png)

how to resolve this?

Comment: Don't you need a valid product key to activate?

Comment: I do not have genuine version of windows and i have installed free version of visual studio 2015 Enterprise edition

Comment: You resolve it by doing what it says...  Getting a license or product key.  If this isn't part of your company, I recommend looking at the Community edition (which is free), as the licenses for Enterprise are...  Pricy

Comment: Your issue is not related to Windows; instead, your trial of Visual Studio has expired. Obtain a key and use "Unlock with a Product Key" link on that screen.